# Monaco Editor - Web Workers cannot be loaded in production build

Tags: reactjs, web-worker, production, monaco-editor, worker-loader

I'm currently implementing the Monaco Editor from Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor), with a plugin for yaml validation, autocompletion, etc. . (https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml) in our react js APP.

[image: Worker Configuration]

[image: Editor Creation]

[image: Imports]

Maybe it is also important to tell you, that our authentication process gets managed via Keycloak.

When I'm running my code in development (React-scripts start) everything is working as expected.
I can create the editor, the schema gets implemented correctly and autocompletion is also working.

BUT as soon as I try to use the editor in PRODUCTION Build it seems that it cant load my workers correctly, following the editor is not working as it should.

I always get these errors in production:

[image: Production Errors #1]

[image: Production Errors #2]

I tried to use monaco-editor-webpack-plugin with React Rewired but it didnt have an positive effect either.

I also tried to use the worker loader to load the workers, but it also didnt help

Any more Ideas how I can fix this ? Has this to do something with CORS ? Because it tries to load files in a url? Or am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

What I tried: Monaco Webpack Plugin, plain webpack, worker-loader
Expected Behaviour: Monaco Editor with Monaco Yaml working in production build.
Current behaviour: Working fine in development build, cannot load workers in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that my keycloak (on a different port) rejected to load the working scripts. After handling this problems, the editor is working fine.